# tween control.reset() of trackball controls js not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, three.js, tween

see this link www.naamdesigns.com/arv

i want to rotate the sphere back to its original position each time any link is clicked.
i'm trying to reset the camera position and its working. But i'm not able to tween the reset rotation. how to do it?

```
function camreset(){
    //var object = new THREE.Object3D();
    new TWEEN.Tween( camera.position )
                    .to( controls.reset() ,5000)
                    .easing( TWEEN.Easing.Exponential.InOut )
                    .onUpdate( render )
                    .start();


    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd start by having a look at what the trackball controls reset function does. The function works by setting the current "target" and "object" positions and "object" up vector for orientation.

```
_this.target.copy( _this.target0 );
_this.object.position.copy( _this.position0 );
_this.object.up.copy( _this.up0 );
```

Excerpt above from r70 Three.js TrackballControls.js. So forget using the reset function, you can once the tween is complete I suppose.

So, assuming your trackball control is called `controls`, I would simply tween the `controls.target` and `controls.object.position` and `controls.object.up` back to their defined defaults as hinted to above `controls.target0`, `controls.position0`, and `controls.up0`. For example:

```
var tweenPositionToReset = new TWEEN.Tween( controls.object.position )
    .to( { x: controls.position0.x, y: controls.position0.y, z: controls.position0.z }, 500 )
    .easing( TWEEN.Easing.Quadratic.In )
    .start();
```

Of course do you'll need to do this for the other two vectors as well. Hope that helps! Good luck